# kotlin data class property not in equals method

Tags: kotlin, data-class

example:

```
data class Test(val name: String, val age: Int)

val a = Test("a", 21)
val b = Test("b", 31)

val result = a == b  // false
```

want `result` return true, what to do?

Comment: have any extensions for age?

Comment: Why would that expression return `true`? The values are different.

Comment: want only compare name, not with age

Comment: `a.name == b.name`? I still don't see how you expect that to return `true`, since `"a"` and `"b"` aren't equal.

Comment: And if you do want that expression to be `true`, then obviously you need to change the values so that they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, it's not clear what you're aiming for here.

By default, two instances of `data class` are considered equal when all the properties in their primary constructor are equal. So in the question, two `Test`s will be equal when they have the same `name` *and* `age`:

```
println(Test("a", 1) == Test("a", 1)) // prints ‘true’
println(Test("a", 1) == Test("b", 1)) // prints ‘false’
println(Test("a", 1) == Test("a", 2)) // prints ‘false’
```

It looks like you want two `Test`s to be considered equal when they have the same `name`, even if they have different `age`s. To do that, you have two main options:

- Override their `equals()` and `hashCode()`<sup>*</sup> methods:

  ```
  data class Test(val name: String, val age: Int) {
      override fun equals(other: Any?) = other is Test && other.name == name
      override fun hashCode() = name.hashCode()
  }
  ```

  That gives `Test` a natural sense of equality, which will apply everywhere two `Test`s are checked, whether you're using `==`, or putting them in a `Set`, or whatever.
- Check the names explicitly at that point in your code:

  ```
  val result = a.name == b.name
  ```

  Obviously, that will only apply to that particular check, and won't affect anything else. So it's simpler for this one case, but you'd have to remember to repeat it anywhere else you want to check for equality in that way.

Which you choose depends on what `Test` *means* in your case, and whether checking only the name is the obvious, natural behaviour that you'll want by default.

---

(However, in the question, that will still result in `a != b`, because `a` and `b` have different names as well as different ages.)

---

(<sup>*</sup> It won't give you an error if you fail to override `hashCode()` as well, but that breaks the contract for `equals()` and is likely to give strange behaviour, such as not being able to find `Test` elements/keys you've added to sets/maps, errors or infinite loops when trying to sort a list of `Test`s, and so on.)

Comment: Only primary constructor parameters of data class are used in equality comparison. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body

Comment: @ocos Ah yes, I knew that but didn't quite say it! Now clarified, thanks.

Comment: Defining `equals` and `hashCode` doesn't give a "natural ordering". You have to define `compareTo` for that.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You're right too, of course! (My excuse is that I wrote my answer in a big hurry…) Thanks for that — I've made a further update.